# How to Cover this Test class related to approval process in Apex

Tags: unit-test

how to cover this test class. Itsn't covering elseif part and else part.Please help me to cover this class

```
public with sharing class lgt_SubmitController {
    public  string dealsheetId {get;set;}
    public boolean flag {get;set;}
    public lgt_SubmitController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        dealsheetId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('dealsheetId'); 

    }
    public  PageReference checkApproval(){
       try{  
        List<DealSheet_Billing_Info__c> dealerList=[SELECT Id from DealSheet_Billing_Info__c where DealSheet__c=:dealsheetId AND Dealer__c!=null];
        if(dealerList.size()==0){
            system.debug('entering list');
            system.debug('no delaer exist');
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error,'No dealer exists on this dealsheet.Please add a dealer to the Dealsheet Dealer/End user related list'));
            flag=true;
            return null;
        }

       else if(Approval.isLocked(dealsheetId)){
           system.debug('record is locked');
           ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error,'This record is currently in an approval process. A record can be in only one approval process at a time.'));
           flag=true;
           return null;
        }
       else
        {



            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
            req1.setObjectId(dealsheetId);
            req1.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId('Dealsheet_Approval');
            //req1.setSkipEntryCriteria(true);
            Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);
              System.assert(result.isSuccess());
             system.debug('status @@@@@@'+result.getInstanceStatus());
              PageReference pageRef=new  PageReference('/'+dealsheetId);
              pageRef.setRedirect(true);
              return pageRef;



        }
    }

    catch (Exception e){
        throw e;

    }
    }
    public  PageReference returnPrevious(){
        PageReference pageRef=new  PageReference('/'+dealsheetId);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;

    }
}
```

======================================================================

```
@isTest
public class lgt_SubmitController_Test {
  public static testmethod void submitApprove(){

    List<Account> testAccountList = TestLibrary.createTestAccounts();
    Account testAccount = testAccountList[0];
    Opportunity baseOpp0 = TestLibrary.createTestOpportunity(testAccount, testAccount);
    Opportunity baseOpp1 = TestLibrary.createTestOpportunity(testAccount, testAccount);
    baseOpp0.Markets__c = 'US';
    baseOpp1.Markets__c = 'CDN';
    DealSheet__c testDS = TestLibrary.createTestDealSheet(baseOpp0,1);
    ApexPages.StandardController sc0 = new ApexPages.standardController(testDS);
           lgt_SubmitController  dsController0 = new  lgt_SubmitController(sc0);
    Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
    req1.setObjectId(testDS.Id);
    dsController0.returnPrevious();
    //Submit the approval request for the change
    Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.Process(req1);
    System.assert(result.isSuccess());

    dsController0.checkApproval();
    PageReference pageRef0 = Page.lgt_SubmitApproval;
    pageRef0.getParameters().put( 'Id',testDS.Id);
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef0);
```

### }

I have tried like this but still itsnt covering

```
     @isTest
 public class lgt_SubmitController_Test {
public static testmethod void submitApprove(){

    List<Account> testAccountList = TestLibrary.createTestAccounts();
    Account testAccount = testAccountList[0];
    Opportunity baseOpp0 = TestLibrary.createTestOpportunity(testAccount, testAccount);
    Opportunity baseOpp1 = TestLibrary.createTestOpportunity(testAccount, testAccount);
    baseOpp0.Markets__c = 'US';
    baseOpp1.Markets__c = 'CDN';
    DealSheet__c testDS = TestLibrary.createTestDealSheet(baseOpp0,1);
    ApexPages.StandardController sc0 = new ApexPages.standardController(testDS);
    lgt_SubmitController  dsController0 = new  lgt_SubmitController(sc0);
       PageReference pageRef0 = Page.lgt_SubmitApproval;
    pageRef0.getParameters().put( 'Id',testDS.Id);
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef0);     
    dsController0.checkApproval();
   dsController0.returnPrevious();


   }

public static testmethod void  submitApprove2(){
    List<Account> testAccountList = TestLibrary.createTestAccounts();
    Account testAccount = testAccountList[0];
    Opportunity baseOpp0 = TestLibrary.createTestOpportunity(testAccount, testAccount);
    Opportunity baseOpp1 = TestLibrary.createTestOpportunity(testAccount, testAccount);
    baseOpp0.Markets__c = 'US';
    baseOpp1.Markets__c = 'CDN';
    DealSheet__c testDS = TestLibrary.createTestDealSheet(baseOpp0,1);
    ApexPages.StandardController sc0 = new ApexPages.standardController(testDS);
     lgt_SubmitController  dsController0 = new  lgt_SubmitController(sc0);

    dsController0.checkApproval();
    dsController0.returnPrevious();

}
 public static testmethod void submitApprove1(){
     List<Account> testAccountList = TestLibrary.createTestAccounts();
    Account testAccount = testAccountList[0];
    Opportunity baseOpp0 = TestLibrary.createTestOpportunity(testAccount, testAccount);
    Opportunity baseOpp1 = TestLibrary.createTestOpportunity(testAccount, testAccount);
    baseOpp0.Markets__c = 'US';
    baseOpp1.Markets__c = 'CDN';
    DealSheet__c testDS = TestLibrary.createTestDealSheet(baseOpp0,1);
    ApexPages.StandardController sc0 = new ApexPages.standardController(testDS);
     lgt_SubmitController  dsController0 = new  lgt_SubmitController(sc0);
    Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
    req1.setObjectId(testDS.Id);

    //Submit the approval request for the change
    Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.Process(req1);
    System.assert(result.isSuccess());


    dsController0.checkApproval();
    dsController0.returnPrevious();
    PageReference pageRef0 = Page.lgt_SubmitApproval;
    pageRef0.getParameters().put( 'Id',testDS.Id);
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef0);

   }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably find it easiest if you set up three unit tests to cover the possible branches.

In the first unit test, do exactly as you've done.

In the second unit test, insert a DealSheet_Billing_Info__c record that matches the criteria, submit the record for approval, and call the checkApproval method.

In the third unit test, insert a DealSheet_Billing_Info__c record that matches the criteria, do not submit the record for approval, and call the checkApproval method.

Note: to get better coverage, remove the try-catch parts of your live code. Since you're just throwing the exception, that's the same as not using try-catch at all, but is artificially lowering your code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you didnot define dealsheetId while you are using it in query.You can try putting this code.Put it right after you define the controller.

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('dealsheetId',testDS .id);
```

Comment: I used it right..But i have tried itsnot covering